# Is Anakin's love for Padme healthy?

Tags: star-wars, love, anakin-skywalker

Which of the following best describes Anakin's feelings for Padme, from a bystander's objective point of view?

Going down from one extreme to the other:

1. Sexual infatuation, nothing more
2. True, healthy love
3. Obsession to possess her
4. Others (Please specify)

Well I think 1 and 3 is different, but I've never been in a relationship myself, much less is an expert in this field, so if I didn't "get it right" feel free to answer this as an open-ended question lol

Comment: Considering he was nine when he met her and decided that he wanted to marry her, I think we can rule out 1, and maybe 3

Comment: Well, there is a letter from LucasFilms which adresses this question -- not sure how 'canonical' that is, but someone could elaborate on it: http://geekdad.com/2015/04/jedi-marry/ Anakin does talk about selfless love in Episodes 2 and 3.

Comment: Are you asking whether his relationship was healthy *before* the point that he murdered hundreds of his friends and dozens of small children because of it? Or *before* the point where he flew into a rage and choked Padme to death?

Comment: How about her love for him? She first met him when he was ten years old. I know she didn’t fall in love with him until much later, but still.

Comment: Define "healthy"? (Or, less snarkily, is there any such thing as a truly objective point of view on a relationship?)

Comment: I think that it was made clear in Attack of the Clones that Padme knew it was NOT healthy, though she eventually went for it anyway. There's no way that getting with someone you cared for when (or who cared for you) they (you) were a child is healthy.